# Subquery returns more than 1 row in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

So I have Two Tables called Emp and Dept..

- **Emp** has ssn, name, supssn, salary, depno
- **Dept** has Dno, name, mgrssn

I'm supposed to get names of those managers who are making less than some of his employees

Right now I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Emp.name
FROM Emp CROSS JOIN Dept
WHERE ((SELECT Emp.salary
   FROM Emp, Dept)>(SELECT Emp.salary
                    FROM Emp, Dept
                    WHERE(Emp.name IN (SELECT Emp.name
                                       FROM Emp CROSS JOIN Dept
                                       WHERE ssn = mgrssn)))) AND (SELECT Emp.depno
                                                                   FROM Emp, Dept)=(SELECT Emp.depno
                                                                                                 FROM Emp, Dept
                    WHERE(Emp.name IN (SELECT Emp.name
                                       FROM Emp CROSS JOIN Dept
                                       WHERE ssn = mgrssn)));
```

What exactly am I missing or adding too much right now?

Comment: I just do not understand your question.

Comment: The user wants to get the names of those employees who are managers and are earning less than his/her employees.

Comment: Without data structure and relationship no one can assumes that how the tables are related to each other. I don't have enough knowledge about mysql but you can avoid your error by using Top 1 in sql server and LIMIT 1 in my sql.

Answer (score 0):

you really need to be patient and organize your question, sir..
but if I understand it correctly, you may try this..
(I assume supssn is the ssn of the manager)

```
SELECT DISTINCT sup.name
FROM emp e join emp sup on e.supssn = sup.ssn
WHERE sup.salary < e.salary
```